# Stubbing AJAX response for JSTree using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, jstree

Trying to help some friends write unit tests for their Javascript but having an issue I've never encountered before. They have a pretty simple use of JStree in an application - where the data is loaded from the server via AJAX call.

```
    var loadHelpValues = function() {
    $('#dhAttrValues').jstree({
        json_data: {
            ajax: {
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: function (node) {
                    if (node == -1) {
                        return "/Item/treeValue/showTreeRoots";
                    } else  {                               
                        return "/Item/treeValue/showTreeChildren?parentId=" + node.attr('valueid') +"&rowId="+node.attr('rowid');
                    }
                },
                data: function(n) {
                    return "dept="+$('#dept').val()+"&attributeId="+$('#dhTitle').data('attributeid');
                },                        
                success: function(new_data, textStatus) {
                    return new_data;
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                    item.checkForSessionTimeoutAndRemoveErrors(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            },
            progressive_render: true,
            progressive_unload: true
        },
        core: {html_titles:true},
        themes: {theme:"apple", dots:false, icons:false},
        plugins: ["themes","json_data"]         
    });
```

This works just fine in the browser but I'm having trouble writing Jasmine tests to validate the behavior. What I have is some minimal fake HTML and I call this function on it. I want to mock out the AJAX call so that I can return some fake data and validate that it displays in the div with the appropriate formatting (Yes - I know that this is basically testing the JSTree widget but this is so we then add additional behavior and tests for click events on those nodes in the future)

Normally in Jasmine whenever I want to stub out the AJAX request so I can put some fake data into my code - I can just use a simple spyOn like this.

```
spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(params){
params.success(
    [
        {"data":"Solid", "attr": {"id":"dhValue521f6364fe334d21c3917da6","valueId":"521f6364fe334d21c3917da6","value":"Solid","title":"Solid","selectable":false},"state":""},
        {"data":"Polka Dot","attr":{"id":"dhValue521f6364fe334d21c3917da8","valueId":"521f6364fe334d21c3917da8","value":"Polka Dot","title":"Polka Dot","selectable":false},"state":""},
    ]
)
```

});

But for some reason this isn't working with JStree - it still keeps trying to make a real AJAX call from my unit tests. I've even validated that in the JStree source it does call $.ajax to get the data from the server, so this *should* work. Tried just about every possible alternative I could think of and searched everywhere.

Has anyone been able to do this? Or able to point me in the direction of what's wrong with my AJAX stub? Is it the fact that JStree was coded as a JQuery Widget that's causing these issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax), this mocks out the XHR request at a lower level, and should work. Full docs on it [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html)